# How to transfer attributes from standalone table to feature class using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, table

In short, I have a stand alone table that has an identical table schema to a feature class.

I am creating a feature in the feature class and need to copy the selected row from the stand alone table into the selected feature.

The Attribute Transfer Tool only allows the source to be another feature class.

I cannot just create a null geometry record in the feature and then add the shape since it participates in a geometric network which does not allow records with null geometry.

Any ideas on how to do this without writing a custom tool?

Comment: Hey Cooter - do you have a key value allowing for a join between the two data sources? If so, you could just create a join and Field Calculate over all of the desired information into the feature class from your table. Alternatively, there is the Join Field(http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000065000000) tool which would save the step of running the Field Calculator - but you would need to delete the original series of fields after Join Field tacks on the set present in the stand-alone table.

Comment: You create a feature (i.e. Alabama) and would like to add the population of Alabama into the attribute table? Wouldn't this be a simple join based on attributes?

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool in Arcgis 10.1 called the [replace geometries too](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01m80000001s000000)l. it is within the advanced editing toolbar. I was able to create a featureclass (point) within a database and add geometries to features following these steps.

1. add an x,y field to your table
2. create a feature class from xy table (values are null so it didnt create features geometries)
3. edit the feature class in arcmap. select the record you want to add geometry to and then click a point.
4. save and done.

this may be too many steps but it is the simplest way I know how to achieve this. once you add geometries you could always copy and paste the features into your main dataset.